# Randomly remove two rows where specific columns are identical

Tags: r

I just have a problem when I was sorting my samples.
Before experiment, I have a data frame,

```
R <- c("a","b","b","a")
S <- rep(c(25,37),,4)
T <-c(1:4,c(3,4,2,1))
O <- c(100:107)
my_data<- data.frame(R,S,T,O)
```

After the experiment,I just found that there is no difference between a and b. Thus I want to randomly remove the rows that are identical in Column R, S,T but no O (O is the id of each sample and this factor didn't affect the result).
How could I perform this?

```
  ##################### resutls 
    R S  T O
 >4 a 37 4 103

 >6 b 37 4 105 #(a=b,randomly select one and remove another)
```

Comment: you can use `duplicated(my_data[2:3])` to check which lines are duplicated.

Comment: Why do you need to randomly remove the rows? You could just use `my_data[-which(duplicated(my_data[2:3])),]` to only keep the first one.

Comment: Hi, all. Many thanks for the comment. It is not necessary but I just wonder if the randomization could be conducted.

Comment: You could still use the duplicated approach if you order `my_data` randomly beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be achieved using `dplyr`. The approach is to group on `S` and `T` and then take the `1st` OR alternatively one from rows selected for group.

**EDIT::** Included another option based on suggestion from @docendodiscimus to use `sample_n()`.

```
# Data 
R <- c("a","b","b","a")
S <- rep(c(25,37),,4)
T <-c(1:4,c(3,4,2,1))
O <- c(100:107)
my_data<- data.frame(R,S,T,O)


ibrary(dplyr)

my_data %>% group_by(S, T) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1)

 # OR It can be made random selection as

 my_data %>% group_by(S, T) %>% 
 filter(row_number() == sample(1:n(),1))


# OR Another option could be use sample_n()
  my_data %>% group_by(S, T) %>% sample_n(1)

# Result 

#  R          S     T     O
#  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 a       25.0  1.00   100
#2 b       37.0  2.00   101
#3 b       25.0  3.00   102
#4 a       37.0  4.00   103
#5 b       25.0  2.00   106
#6 a       37.0  1.00   107
```

Comment: dplyr has a `sample_n` function to do this

Comment: @docendodiscimus That would be really smart. Thanks. I wasn't aware about that function.

Comment: Thank you all ! That is really fantastic and helpful!